# Is there a more elegant way of handcrafting serialised Javascript in .Net?

Tags: javascript, .net, serialization

I receive this error when I try to use "{" to generate Javascript objects server-side to pass back to the browser: "Input string was not in a correct format."

This happens when I do the following:

```
builder.AppendLine(String.Format("ID{0}: { ", application.Key.ToString())); // Does not work:
```

But not when I do the following:

```
builder.AppendLine(String.Format("ID{0}: {{ ", application.Key.ToString()));
```

The cause of the error is that String.Format uses "{" as mark-up. Is there a more eligant way of handcrafting Javascript serialisation in .Net?

**EDIT:**

We only have up to .Net 3.5 Framework installed on the server

Comment: No other way, to escape `{` you have to use `{{` or simply don't use `String.Format`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) do what you need?

Comment: I've just edited to say that we do not have .Net 4.0 on the server

Comment: it's availaible on 3.5: new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(yourObject)

Answer (score 3):

I think the usual way to do this would be using JSON and the excellent Json.NET library - http://json.codeplex.com/ . You can just pass in .Net objects and let it take care of the serialization for you:

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(netObject);
```

...Then on the client side use the (jQuery or native browser) parseJSON method to turn that string into Javascript objects.